# VB.net and OpenQA Selenium. Trying to click a button in a Wordpress website

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having issues trying to click a button on a WordPress site. The site's code is difficult to navigate. This is the code I have thus far.

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Create a new ChromeDriver instance
        Dim driver As New ChromeDriver()
        ' Navigate to the URL
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.airexpert.net/2023dreamteam")
        ' Find the button element by its ID and click it
        Dim bodyElement As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#y9ar97_0_offer"))
        ' Find the button element with the id "choice_57" within the body element
        Dim button As IWebElement = bodyElement.FindElement(By.Id("choice_101"))
        ' Click on the button element
        button.Click()
        ' Quit the driver to close the browser
        driver.Quit()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I was trying to click a button but navigating to it seems hard in code.

Answer (score 0):

The button you are trying to click is in an IFRAME. You have to switch context to that IFRAME to be able to see anything inside it. You already had the IFRAME located but named it `bodyElement`. I've updated your code below.

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Create a new ChromeDriver instance
        Dim driver As New ChromeDriver()
        ' Navigate to the URL
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.airexpert.net/2023dreamteam")
        ' Find the IFRAME and switch into it
        .SwitchToFrame driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#y9ar97_0_offer"))
        ' Click the button element with the id "choice_57"
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("choice_101")).Click()
        ' Quit the driver to close the browser
        driver.Quit()
    End Sub
End Module
```